# Can I cook chicken in the over after leaving them sitting in the oven all night?

Tags: food-safety, chicken

I put some wings in the oven last night and then forgot about them and my roommate turned the oven off. They weren't fully cooked but is it still okay to fully cook them now and eat them or would it be better to throw them out?

Answer (score -3):

It isn't worth taking the risk!